# Zipping commands and directory (Windows) Troubles

Tags: python, zip, php-ziparchive

The problem is 'I want a program which creates a backup of all my important files'.

This lesson is located at: http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/problem-solving.html

```
 import os
import time

# 1. The files and directories to be backed up are specified in a list.
source = ['/home/swaroop/byte', '/home/swaroop/bin']
# If you are using Windows, use source = [r'C:\Documents', r'D:\Work'] or something like that

# 2. The backup must be stored in a main backup directory
target_dir = '/mnt/e/backup/' # Remember to change this to what you will be using

# 3. The files are backed up into a zip file.
# 4. The name of the zip archive is the current date and time
target = target_dir + time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') + '.zip'

# 5. We use the zip command (in Unix/Linux) to put the files in a zip archive
zip_command = "zip -qr '%s' %s" % (target, ' '.join(source))

# Run the backup
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    print 'Successful backup to', target
else:
    print 'Backup FAILED'
```

I'm using Windows. 
For # 2, where is this and does it apply to Windows?
For # 5, I can't find the commands to zip a file for the default windows zipping program.

This would be easy if the lesson explained how to use this with Windows and the zipping commands. Any assistance is appreciated. This is homework reading but It's not helpful when all the applicable tools are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a `zip` program from http://info-zip.org/Zip.html but I would recommend just using Python's [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) module.

Also, there's no standard backup file location. You'll just have to make one up.

Comment: Excellent. The d/l mirrors for that program is frozen :( 

I need to read about that module than. 

When I make a backup file location, I can just make a new folder on my desktop and use that, right? 

thanks!

Comment: You can get an older (but still useful) version of `zip` at ftp://garbo.uwasa.fi/pc/arcers/. And you can just use a folder on your desktop for backups.